# SystemVerilog near "end": synt error, unexpected end

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

other questions seem to be missing semicolons, dont see where i might have?
otherwise, what could it be?

```
 //fa module

module full_adder(
    input logic sum, cout,
    output logic    x, y, cin);//interface logic

//internal signals
logic c1, c2, s1;

//circuit
always_comb
begin
s1 = x^y;
c1 = x&y;
sum = s1^cin;
c2 = s1&cin;
cout = c1|c2;
end

end module
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean `endmodule` instead of `end module`?